# Anchor tag changes the margin of the whole div

Tags: html, css

I am making a sort of section with one side being a h1 and anchor and one side being an image. However, I am having troubles moving the anchor tag as its not working at all with margin since it adds margin to the entire div. This does not apply to the h1.

Output I want is that I'd like the anchor tag to be moveable with margin etc. without moving the entire div and stuff like that.

```css
.make-account {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  background-color: #EBCEBF;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.make-account h1 {
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FDF8F5;
}

.make-account img {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.make-account a {
  color: #FDF8F5;
  background-color: #266150;
  padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="make-account">
  <h1>WE HELP YOU FIND YOUR OWN SPORTBUDDY!</h1>

  <a href="#">MAKE AN ACCOUNT</a>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
</div>
```

Edit: How I recognized the problem now is that since it's a `flex-flow: row`
It recognizes the  tag and  tag as items, same with , my output that I want is one div with the background-color taking up 50% and that div having an  and  positioned within them using margin and not being their own items, and another item being the img taking up the other 50%.

Comment: Movable _where_? Please revise to be more specific. Why not just put it in a structural element like a div?

Comment: what do you mean with "moving the anchor tag"? "Moving the anchor tag without the entire div"? I have no idea what you trying to ask. Makes no sense to me. Please be more Specific and detailed about what you trying to do or what the issue is. Might help if you not throw terms around.

Comment: added margin to the anchor with it adding margin to the entire div, like I've done to the h1

Comment: Anchors are inline by default and therefore not great as structural flex elements. Wrap it in a div and be happy.

Comment: you cant add a margin to the anchor. Anchor is not an element it a method to scroll to an element with a specific ID. What you proberly mean is an offset which would require JS

Comment: @tacoshy anchor is definitely an element and not a method, not sure what you're trying to explain here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). And you can certainly add a margin to it.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones i guess I was to tired to read correctly I though he talks about the anchor method to scroll to an id not tha <a> tag itself. I guess the hash in the hyper reference threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your  style

```
aside {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
```

and make sure to wrap the H1 and A in an aside or whatever you like, make sure to edit the style accordingly.

```
<div class="make-account">
    <aside>      
        <h1>WE HELP YOU FIND YOUR OWN SPORTBUDDY!</h1>
        <a href="#">MAKE AN ACCOUNT</a>
</aside>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
</div>
```

I hope this answer helps you out in your further endeavours!

Comment: Did not work, I want the intended ouput to be like this [image](https://prnt.sc/10gfwdh)
But the anchor tag simply cannot have any margin without it adding margin to the div

Comment: @SenorPIe now that we have the example image its easier to help you, i will edit my "awnser" in a couple minutes to a more suitable one for your case